# Django select max id

Tags: python, django

given a standard model (called Image) with an autoset 'id', how do I get the max id?

So far I've tried:

```
max_id = Image.objects.all().aggregate(Max('id'))
```

but I get a 'id__max' Key error.

Trying

```
max_id = Image.objects.order_by('id')[0].id
```

gives a 'argument 2 to map() must support iteration' exception

Any help?

Comment: Why do you want the max id?  Do you want the last thing loaded?  The thing with the largest date?  The ID's are random numbers, they don't mean much and there's no guarantee that max(id) has any useful properties at all.  What are you *really* trying to do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087670/how-to-aggregate-over-a-single-queryset-in-django

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Just order by reverse id, and take the top one.

```
Image.objects.all().order_by("-id")[0]
```

Comment: Isn't this going to evaluate the queryset and perform object construction? `Image.objects.values('id').aggregate(min_id=Min('id'))` would produce a single-key dict containing the min_id. Maybe this wasn't possible 10 years ago.

Comment: django keeps an index on the id column by default so the aggregate will be much slower esp. for large tables.  Daniel's answer performs best although it would be even better with a .values('id')

Answer (score 73):

In current version of django (1.4) it is even more readable

`Image.objects.latest('id').id`

Comment: If there are no objects this will throw a Image.DoesNotExist exception

Comment: Yes and previous answer will raise IndexError in this case.

Comment: It works on any field. Look at the source. It is just syntax sugar for `QuerySet.order_by('-%s' % field)[:1].get()`.

Comment: Only works if there is at least one object, try catch would be appropriate along with this.

Comment: To save other people time, this is how you would do it: `from django.db import models
max_id = None
try:
    max_id = Image.objects.latest('id').id
except models.DoesNotExist:
    pass`

Answer (score 19):

I know this already has a right answer but here it's another way of doing it:

```
prev = Image.objects.last()
```

This gives you the last object.

Comment: I prefer  `.last()` over `.latest()` as **`.last()` will not raise an exception if the queryset is empty**. For other differences between the two, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73298176/11875147).

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me

[model].objects.last().id

```
Image.objects.last().id
```

Answer (score 3):

Your logic is right, this will return the max id

```
res = Image.objects.filter().aggregate(max_id=Max('pk'))
res.get('max_id')
```

Comment: filter() is redundant, just res = Image.objects.aggregate(max_id=Max('pk'))

Answer (score 3):

this also work perfectly:

```
max_id = Image.objects.values('id').order_by('-id').first()
```

Answer (score -2):

Latest object without catching exception and using django orm:

`Image.objects.filter().order_by('id').first()`

Comment: First would return the smallest id, wouldn't it?
Shouldn't you use last()? or '-' with id to give descending?