# How to use "group by and select the max one" in django

Tags: mysql, django, group-by, max

I have a table in MySQL, like:

```
id  dirId filename
 1   1      jone
 2   1      jack
 3   2      jack
 4   3      ella
```

I want to get the biggest `dir_id`(and `filename`) with the same `filename`. 
We can use `group by` in MySQL, what to use in django?

Comment: Can you show those relevant **`models`** ?

Comment: Probably duplicated of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884509/django-select-max-id

Comment: Do you want the corresponding id as well?

Answer (score 0):

I used those code to get it:
        1.A1=ModelClass.objects.all()
        2.A2=A1.values_list('filename',flat='True').distinct()
        3.for itr in A2:
              A1.filter(filename=itr).order_by('dirId')
don't know it's fast enough.

Answer (score -1):

you can use group by syntax in django like this.

```
ModelClass.objects.filter(...).values('filename').annotate(dir_id=models.Max('dirId'))
```